# how data is stored in the storage device in IPFS

Tags: storage, ipfs

I am going through the concept of IPFS. And one of the important aspect in IPFS is Bitswapping which basically deals with how blocks of data are requested using the wantlists.

My question is with regards to once a peer gets the wantlists from other peers,

- how does it actually fetch the data from the actual storage device?
- What are the steps involved in it?
- How does the conversion happen with respect to different storage protocols based on the bitswap requests.

Please help me with these answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning, so questions like this are a good opportunity to dig deeper :)

> how does it actually fetch the data from the actual storage device?
>   What are the steps involved in it?

Based on the Bitswap api docs, it looks like bitswap operates on a provided libp2p instance and blockstore instance.

The blockstore instance is an abstraction over actual data storage, which could be software abstraction of anything - storage service like S3, virtualized device, or real device.

Based on the configuration bits I've read though, fetching could be done over whichever transports the libp2p instance was configured with, and any connected nodes also support (on per node basis).

Assuming multiple transports are supported on both ends between two nodes, I don't know how *best* connection is negotiated/dictated by libp2p...

> How does the conversion happen with respect to different storage protocols based on the bitswap requests.

IIUC, at the block level there would not be any conversion happening - that would happen at a higher level in the stack (IPLD).

I read through these to get a better understanding:

- [Bitswap spec](https://github.com/ipfs/specs/tree/master/bitswap)
- [JS-IPFS Bitswap implementation](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-bitswap#readme)
- [JS-IPFS Blockservice](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-block-service)